# Which one is the most suitable way to store small amount of data in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, json, sqlite, xaml, windows-8

I need to know what is the best way to save a small amount of data generated by a simple agenda app for Windows Store. I looked around the internet and found the SQLite database and the JSon serialization. Which one should i use? Unfortunately i was not able to find any material that suited me. Is there any place i can find a good tutorial about how to use one of these technologies?

Obs: I'm using Windows 8, not 8.1 and i'm developing with XAML and C#.

Comment: SQLite database and the JSon serialization serves different purpose. you cannot store data in Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your needs. If you have simple data that do not requires indexation, storing your data using serialization (Json, Xml or [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)) is a very good and simple option. I really like protobuf ([also available on nugget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net)) because it is a binary format (small footprint) and easy to use. You can either user the protobuf dsl or [attributes](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted) (code-first like).

If you have more complex data scheme and need more features like indexation or transactions it is better to choose SQLite or [Esent](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/).